# Crash when Fetched Results Controller updates table after saving a background MOC

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableView hooked up to a FRC (Fetched Results Controller) , I also have two contexts , namely backgroundContext initialised in a private queue and a mainContext initialised on the main queue. I also have setup the didSaveNotification to pass the objects from one context to another. When ever i save some data in the backgroundContext it saves successfully and FRC updates ,but if i repeat the process again the app crashes with an error

> 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an
>   NSArray or an NSSet.'

The saving is done through a form which is presented modally. The same viewController works fine if presented in other viewControllers . but crashes only in one particular one. But again other that presenting the Form no other extra stuff is being done.

Here's my entire crash report.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL
>   or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103575495 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000102fbb99e objc_exception_throw + 43  2   Foundation
>
>   0x00000001003c706b -[NSPredicateOperator
>   performOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 826     3   Foundation
>
>   0x00000001003c6c1e -[NSComparisonPredicate
>   evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 314  4   Foundation
>
>   0x00000001003c6ae2 -[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:] + 19    5
>
>   CoreData                            0x0000000102d61d06
>   -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _objectInResults:] + 102     6   CoreData                            0x0000000102d630f7
>   -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _preprocessUpdatedObjects:insertsInfo:deletesInfo:updatesInfo:sectionsWithDeletes:newSectionNames:treatAsRefreshes:]
>   + 519     7   CoreData                            0x0000000102d642d5 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 1781     8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035cad9c
>   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 12   9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010352d51d
>   _CFXNotificationPost + 2381   10  Foundation                          0x000000010035b7fa -[NSNotificationCenter
>   postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68   11  CoreData
>   0x0000000102c9048a
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 74    12  CoreData                            0x0000000102d16c8b
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:]
>   + 331     13  CoreData                            0x0000000102c8c9cc -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _postRefreshedObjectsNotificationAndClearList] + 108   14  CoreData                            0x0000000102c8c5e4
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2804  15  CoreData                            0x0000000102c663cb _performRunLoopAction + 267  16  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000103540dc7
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103540d37
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391  18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103520522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010351fd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467     20  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001037ecf04 GSEventRunModal + 161  21  UIKit
>   0x00000001011bde33 UIApplicationMain + 1010   22  Expense_Manager
>   0x0000000100001d13 main + 115     23  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010420c7e1 start + 0 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the predicate look like?

Comment: `request =  [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ExpenseTransactions"];
predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category = %@",self.passedCategoryObj];` Category and ExpenseTransactions are two entities having a one-tomany relationship.

Comment: Can you log out `self.passedCategoryObj` at the point when it crashes? My guess is that it's `nil`

Comment: Its not nil , i logged it. And if it helps, cellForRowAtIndexPath  does get called and its somewhere midway of reloading the table it crashes.

Comment: What thread is this on?

Comment: the reloading ? or logging the self.passedCategoryObj ? , btw both are on the main thread.

Comment: What type is `self.passedCategoryObj` when logged out?

Comment: it's an NSManagedObject type. But what puzzles me , is that it works fine for the first time, but when i save again it crashes.

Comment: Is it the same type the first time it's logged? Are you sure it's this predicate that's crashing?

Comment: Yes it is , And yeah it's this same predicate because it work's the first time i try saving data. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54474/discussion-between-paul-s-and-navindev).

Comment: Its been a while but anyway I solved it , check out my answer and thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i actually found out why this was happening a few days ago. There was a notification being fired off when the form dismissed which reloaded a tableView from another viewController hooked up to an FRC sharing the same context. Once I removed itself as an observer in viewDidDisappear it did not crash. :) I hope this helps incase someone is facing the same problem.