# CoreData & RestKit crash: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, restkit-0.20

I'm facing a strange CoreData related crash.

I'm using RestKit2 which has parent-child relationship between mainMOC and persistentMOC.
What seems to cause the crash (but hardly reproducable) is to store a new entity into CoreData (using mainMOC) and later try to retrieve object having relationship with previously stored entity (again using main MOC).

Stack trace doesn't contain any indication that it's coming from my code. Seems something fishy in merging the two contexts.
Crash happens on both iOS7 and iOS8 and on both Device and Simulator.

Does someone have experience with this?

```
2014-10-15 11:25:56.208 MyApplication[77240:14758953] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x04e97df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x04b21a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   Foundation                          0x04179816 -[NSEqualityPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x04178b05 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 345
    4   Foundation                          0x0426e387 -[NSSubqueryExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 627
    5   Foundation                          0x04178c8c -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 231
    6   Foundation                          0x04178aa2 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 246
    7   Foundation                          0x041a9776 -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator evaluatePredicates:withObject:substitutionVariables:] + 254
    8   Foundation                          0x041a95ec -[NSCompoundPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 292
    9   Foundation                          0x041a9776 -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator evaluatePredicates:withObject:substitutionVariables:] + 254
    10  Foundation                          0x041a95ec -[NSCompoundPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 292
    11  Foundation                          0x041789a4 -[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:] + 48
    12  CoreData                            0x048d836d -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _objectInResults:] + 109
    13  CoreData                            0x048d9d10 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _preprocessUpdatedObjects:insertsInfo:deletesInfo:updatesInfo:sectionsWithDeletes:newSectionNames:treatAsRefreshes:] + 672
    14  CoreData                            0x048db28a __77-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 1946
    15  CoreData                            0x047e8454 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 196
    16  CoreData                            0x047e8337 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 231
    17  CoreData                            0x048daacf -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 127
    18  Foundation                          0x0411b929 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 40
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x04e62974 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x04d5061b _CFXNotificationPost + 3051
    21  Foundation                          0x0410af26 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
    22  CoreData                            0x047c94d3 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 83
    23  CoreData                            0x0486954f -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 367
    24  CoreData                            0x047c4d78 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _postRefreshedObjectsNotificationAndClearList] + 136
    25  CoreData                            0x047c483b -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 4875
    26  CoreData                            0x047c3516 -[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges] + 54
    27  CoreData                            0x047969d7 _performRunLoopAction + 327
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x04dbafbe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x04dbaf00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x04db093a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x04db01ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x04daffdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x05e4224f GSEventRunModal + 192
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x05e4208c GSEventRun + 104
    35  UIKit                               0x02f56e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    36  MyApplication                       0x000a9e04 main + 164
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x06483ac9 start + 1
)
```

Comment: Seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877842

Comment: What FRCs have you configured and how are they setup?

Comment: There are 2 FRCs used in two separate table views. Both use MOC intended to be used on main queue. Each FRC has it's own fetchRequest.